# importing CSV data in Oracle (trying Apex/SQL Developer)

Tags: sql, oracle, csv, import, oracle-apex

I initially asked this on Superuser, but somebody advised me to repost here.

I am using recent versions of APEX (4.1.1) and Oracle (11.2.0.3).

I am uploading CSV data to a set of tables.
I have been trying it out and am encountering some problems which I haven’t seen before.

As an example, I tried to import data to this table:

```
CREATE TABLE SW_ENGINEER 
   (ENGINEER_NO VARCHAR2(10), 
          ENGINEER_NAME VARCHAR2(50), 
           CONSTRAINT SW_ENG_PK PRIMARY KEY (ENGINEER_NO))
```

It fails on this simplified data subset:

```
call log no,contract_no,call date,agreed date,agreed time,actual arrive,engineer no,engineer name,equipment code,cust desc,eng desc
a,b,c,22-Mar-06,1,23/03/2006 15:00,654,Flynn Hobbs,d,e,f
a,b,c,22-Mar-06,2,23/03/2006 15:00,654,Flynn Hobbs,d,e,f
a,b,c,19-Mar-06,3,19/03/2006 09:15,351,Rory Juarez,d,e,f
```

(It fails the same way on a larger data set)
I can’t load it with either APEX or SQL Developer, as follows:

- APEX: With APEX Data Workshop, import text, load existing table, use comma separated, select the table and the file, tick the checkbox for ‘header row’, and we have the column mapping form showing the right data. Then set all columns except engineer_no and engineer_name as ‘No’, and click Load Data.

This appears to work, and displays a summary row in the Text Data Load Repository, but on inspection it has loaded 0 rows and 79 failed. Clicking the 79 shows that they all suffered from "ORA-01008: not all variables bound". The selected columns look OK to me, so I’m wondering whether it is still including some of the others in spite of the ‘No’ settings ?

The problem doesn't occur if I edit the csv to remove irrelevant columns before uploading, but it would be a lot easier if I could use column mapping.

- SQL Developer: Using the import data wizard in SD, I find that it won’t progress to column mapping unless Header Row is checked (the button is enabled but doesn’t function - why not ?), - but if it is checked (correctly in this case) then the Verify step fails because “Table Column Engineer_no is not big enough ...”.

I found that can be overcome by removing the header values from the csv file columns. So it appears that setting the Header Row checkbox does not actually cause it ignore the header row at all, and it is the header value ‘engineer-no’ which is causing the error. Which doesn’t seem right to me. 
I’ve used both approaches without a problem in the past, and am wondering whether the recent upgrade has anything to do with this.

Any ideas ? Or am I missing something obvious ?

Comment: Do any of the fields in the csv file have a `,` in them?

Comment: yes but then they are quoted "like, this"

Comment: Have you tested a simple 1 or 2 line csv without such fields.  And another 1 or 2 line csv with such fields?  If the former fails, you have a bigger problem.  If the former succeeds and the latter fails, you've isolated the problem.  If both succeed there is some other peculiarity in your data somewhere.  Analyse it in Excel or something.

Comment: Even the top three rows (the ones I include here) alone fail to be imported. I don't see anything that should break the import... But obviously not looking in the right direction.

Comment: Few hours left for the bounty... So it's an APEX bug, the least-worst workaround is to stick the columns we want at the left end of the CSV file, is that it? I feel stupid awarding myself my own bounty here :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A colleague of mine finds this (not totally satisfying) solution:

if the columns you require are both at the beginning, it works, like this:

```
engineer no,engineer name,equipment code,cust desc,eng desc,call log no,contract_no,call date,agreed date,agreed time,actual arrive
654,Flynn Hobbs,d,e,f,a,b,c,22-Mar-06,1,23/03/2006 15:00
654,Flynn Hobbs,d,e,f,a,b,c,22-Mar-06,2,23/03/2006 15:00
351,Rory Juarez,d,e,f,a,b,c,19-Mar-06,3,19/03/2006 09:15
```

So it looks like a bug with the YES/NO include functionality in APEX text import?

Answer (score 0):

In CSV

```
call log no,contract_no,call date,agreed date,agreed time,actual arrive,engineer no,engineer name,equipment code,cust desc,eng desc
a,b,c,22-Mar-06,1,23/03/2006 15:00,654,Flynn Hobbs,d,e,f
a,b,c,22-Mar-06,2,23/03/2006 15:00,654,Flynn Hobbs,d,e,f
a,b,c,19-Mar-06,3,19/03/2006 09:15,351,Rory Juarez,d,e,f
```

You have 11 columns and you try to import it in 3 columns.

1. If you have " in csv you shoud delete them all.
2. You need to have exactly 11 column in table for this CSV.
3. Every column in table could have right data type.
4. Every , in CSV is a Column separator.

Answer (score 0):

I am not quite sure why it didn't work for you. It worked fine for me, using the Apex Data Workshop with copy and paste. (Version 5.0.4)

Of course, I was only able to upload two of those three results, one of them had a duplicate ID value. But it worked.

PS: For the larger data set where you may have  ',' as a part of the column value for a row, consider using "Optionally enclosed by" option by setting them up with double-quotes (") during the upload wizard. It treats the whole value as one value.